# background position for a sprite image not working in IE for a count down clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an awesome count down clock which works fine in chrome but does not work at all in IE. Thanks to Stack overflow user Roko for helping me out to put together the project. Would anyone have any idea how to get this work on IE?

Here is the JS

```
var fut = new Date("Dec 19 2013 21:15:00 UTC-05:00")
    obj = {};

// Number splitter
function intSpl( i ){
  i = Math.floor(i);
  return [~~(i/10), i%10];  
}

function drawTime(){  
  var now = new Date().getTime(),   
      dif = now<fut ? Math.floor( (fut-now)/1000) : 0;
  obj.s = intSpl(dif % 60);
  obj.m = intSpl(dif/60 % 60);
  obj.h = intSpl(dif/60/60 % 24);
  obj.d = intSpl(dif/60/60/24);  

  for(var key in obj){    
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        for(var i=0; i<2; i++){ 
            $('#'+ key+i).css({backgroundPosition: -obj[key][i]*50 });
        }
     }    
  }  
}
drawTime(); 
setInterval(drawTime, 1000);
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qLTE2/7/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Reason is dateformat is not supported in the IE, I have tested in IE8. it is working fine.`var fut = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 12, 19, 21, 15, 0));` //changed format, i.e date format should be - `new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);`

Ref: link about date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate

```
//var fut = new Date("Dec 19 2013 21:15:00 UTC-05:00");

var fut = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 12, 12, 21, 15, 0)); //format - new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
obj = {};

//Number splitter
function intSpl( i ){
    i = Math.floor(i);
    return [~~(i/10), i%10];  
}




function drawTime(){  
    var now = new Date().getTime(); 

    var  dif = now<fut ? Math.floor( (fut-now)/1000) : 0;

    console.log("fut::"+fut +":::now"+now); // fut is NaN thats why it is not working

    obj.s = intSpl(dif % 60);
    obj.m = intSpl(dif/60 % 60);
    obj.h = intSpl(dif/60/60 % 24);
    obj.d = intSpl(dif/60/60/24);  


        for(var key in obj){    
              if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                 for(var i=0; i<2; i++){ 
                     $('#'+ key+i).css({backgroundPosition: -obj[key][i]*50 });       

                     console.log(key+":::"+i+':::PX set'+ -obj[key][i]*50);
                 }
              }    
        }  
    }

    drawTime(); 
    setInterval(drawTime, 1000);
```

CSS:

```
    #clock span{
      display:inline-block;
      width:50px;
      height:85px;
      background-image:url('time.jpg');
      background-position:0 0;
      /*background-color: #ffff00;*/ //added for testing
    }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qLTE2/8/